# Spring MVC web application - Permission mechanism for a bank application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, permissions

We are now exploring the options for a bank web application permission mechanism.

We have a very simple use case that more or less will define our requirements in terms of permissions needs:

"A user logs in, and approve a transaction of sum 5000$. His role "Transaction Manager" allowed him to **VIEW** the entry of the transaction. and his role was allowing him to **APPROVE** transactions of sum <= 6000$"

Are there any frameworks \ libraries that expose a clean API to achieve that?
Our old project is using the permission model of "Domain \ Action \ Instance" and we think the requirement above is too complex to achieve with that model.

Comment: Also see http://hdiv.org

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security is a de-facto standard for securing Spring MVC apps, the Spring MVC documentation actually discusses it under the [Web Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-web-security) chapter.

It provides authentication and role-based authorization that you can easily integrate with whatever underlying ACL system you have, or plan to put in place

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring-security, which will provide role  based implementation and also token based login.